# yum downgrade and automatically include all dependencies?

Tags: centos, yum

When upgrading a package, yum resolves and updates all dependencies automatically. Is there a flag/option when downgrading packages. For instance i have php82 installed and am trying to get back to php 74.

`sudo yum downgrade php-7.4.33-8.el7.remi.x86_64`

which returns the error:

```
Error: Package: php-tidy-8.2.9-2.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php82)
```

I can add `php-tidy` to the downgrade list as well, but there will be dozens of these dependencies. Can I just instruct yum to automatically downgrade all of them as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to downgrade all PHP packages

```
yum-config-manager --disable 'remi-php*'
yum-config-manager --enable   remi-php74
yum downgrade php\*
yum update
```

First, ensure proper repository configuration, so only the expected PHP version is available.

Then, as the downgrade command may downgrade some packages not from PHP stack itself (pecl extensions, noarch libraries) the final update will bring all the latest versions.

An alternative way, probably better if no manually installed RPM:

```
yum-config-manager --disable 'remi-php*'
yum-config-manager --enable   remi-php74
yum distro-sync
```

But please notice that CentOS 7 is now terribly old and close to its end of life in less than 1 year, updating to a more recent version is recommended.

Such downgrade is much easier on EL-8 or EL-9 thanks to modularity (switching enabled stream will sync all packages in this stream).

```
dnf module switch-to php:remi-7.4
```